# Visual swing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

Is there any way I can use a visual editor to make swing applications in Eclipse?  I'm using Ganymede.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Jigloo](http://www.cloudgarden.com/jigloo/index.html) a fair bit and it is quite good.  Can generate GUIs for both Swing and SWT.  Free for non-commercial use, and pretty affordable at $US85 per developer for commercial use.  Works fine with 3.4 (Ganymede).

Comment: Good link. I will give it a try. +1

Answer (score 9):

Your options are:

1. [WindowBuilder Pro](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) (eclipse.org): "WindowBuilder is a powerful and easy to use bi-directional Java GUI designer", see also [WindowBuilder Pro on code.google.com](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/index.html).
2. [Visual Swing for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/p/visualswing4eclipse/) - an editor that works directly with the .java source files. Notes:

   1. The update url on the front page is wrong ([issue 115](http://code.google.com/p/visualswing4eclipse/issues/detail?id=115)), should instead be: `http://visualswing4eclipse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/vs4e/`
   2. You have to untick "Group items by category" to be able to see the install.
   3. The [original announcement of visual swing for eclipse](http://eclipse.dzone.com/announcements/visual-swing-designer-eclipse).
   4. Crashed for me when opening a netbeans-generated swing file.
3. [Visual Editor from ehecht.com](http://www.ehecht.com/eclipse_ve/ve.html)  - someone's own version, last updated 2010-08-29: "prelininary [sic] eclipse 3.6 (helios) version" (direct download: [ve_eclipse_36_win32_201008292115.zip](http://www.ehecht.com/eclipse_ve/ve_eclipse_36_win32_201008292115.zip)) *"These files are non official builds. So you use it on [sic] your own risk."*
4. Use [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) instead

   1. Built-in GUI editor
   2. Uses an xml file as the source for gui design, performing a one-way conversion
   3. Adds its own libraries to your project to support GUI creation.
5. [Jigloo SWT/Swing GUI Builder for Eclipse and WebSphere](http://www.cloudgarden.com/jigloo/index.html) - *Note: Jigloo is free for non-commercial use, but purchase of a Professional License is required for commercial use (after successfully evaluating Jigloo).*

---

Options no longer viable / available:

- Official "Visual Editor", [archived by eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/archived/): (Archived: June 2011), the matching install instructions at http://wiki.eclipse.org/VE/Update, and the outdated article / tutorial at http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-VE-Custom-Widget/customwidget.html, see also [Is eclipse visual editor dead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319242/is-eclipse-visual-editor-dead)

---

This is a summary of all the other answers to this question as it took me a while to make sense of them.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to install [echech's version of VE](http://www.ehecht.com/eclipse_ve/ve.html) ([Visual Editor](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-VE-Custom-Widget/customwidget.html)).
You have [here another setup procedure](http://wiki.eclipse.org/VE/Update) to follow if the first does not work

[image: OriginalEventsMenu]

It should work with with eclipse3.4 (Ganymede).
Or you could download the original version and install it in a eclipse3.2 setup.

It is the only [Visual Editor](http://www.eclipse.org/vep/WebContent/main.php) I <del>know</del> knew of which <del>is</del> was free and support Swing.
Note: it is an archived Eclipse project since June 2011.

[tehvan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61848/tehvan) mentions a commercial editor: <del>[SwingDesigner](http://www.xmarks.com/site/www.instantiations.com/swing-designer/)</del> (now only [WBPro for Smalltalk](http://www.instantiations.com/products/add-ons/windowbuilderpro.html) remains)

Comment: "tehvan mentions a commercial editor: SwingDesigner" <- dead link

Comment: @TimAbell: true, that product is no longer available, and I have updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to give a try at [this free Swing visual editor](http://code.google.com/p/visualswing4eclipse/) for eclipse. I had not time to give it a run already but that's on my todo list (this editor looks interesting and it is open source).

Answer (score 0):

this is something better than VE

[Visual Swing for Eclipse](http://eclipse.dzone.com/announcements/visual-swing-designer-eclipse)