# eclipse visual editor

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-editor

Today I tried to install visual editor and every link I found lead or to 404 page or to http://www.eclipse.org/archived/ which tells that it was archived in the previous month. Are there any update site left I can use to install visual editor? I am just not happy to download 400+ megabytes to install visual editor offline.

Comment: Why don't you use [WindowBuilder Pro](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/javadevtools/wbpro/quick_start.html)?

Comment: see also see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564156/visual-swing-in-eclipse

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe Visual Editor is deprecated.

Instead, you should probably install [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) which is available either as a plug-in or as part of the official [Eclipse 3.7 Indigo release](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/indigor) for Java developers.

My impression is that WindowBuilder is a very good GUI-building tool and will be the main GUI editor for Eclipse in the future.

Answer (score 3):

I don't suggest using the Visual Editor project - it is not updated/developed any more. If you need a visual editor for Eclipse, I suggest using [WindowBuilder](http://eclipse.org/windowbuilder/).

Answer (score 2):

You can try this site : http://wiki.eclipse.org/VE/Installing
There is all you need to install Visual Editor.