# Java Eclipse Swing Designing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual swing in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564156/visual-swing-in-eclipse)

can anyone give me a java swing form designer, like a plugin to eclipse.
Have googled for months and hanvt found any good.
Please help!

Comment: If anything you found (by exhaustive search for months) is not good enough how do you think we can help? What have you found so far? Why are they not good? What features do you want?

Comment: Please read the [faq#reputation].

Comment: I voted to close, but on review of the previous question, it is 2 yrs older than this one, and the answers are vastly different. Voting to re-open.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest contribution to Eclipse GUI builders was made by Google. Check out [Window Builder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) - really awesome tool!

Comment: Thank you! im installing in eclipse right now!

Comment: Man, when i design something, and then browse another class, it wont save. You know a good tutorial? :D

Comment: Please help! I would be very happy

Answer (score 1):

There is the [WindowBuilder Pro](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/palettes/swing_palette.html) from Google, that can be installed as Eclipse plugin. There is also the [JGoodies JFormDesigner](http://www.formdev.com/jformdesigner/), but I'm not sure whether it can be used as a plugin.